# I am creating a JAXWS based Webservice, getting Could not parse hibernate configuration file when deploying the ear file

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

I am developing the JAXWS based web service using jboss developer 6.0.1.GA. I was able to create the web service, but when deploying the ear file in the jboss server, I am getting the below error:

11:23:07,323 ERROR [STDERR] log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).

11:23:07,324 ERROR [STDERR] log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

11:23:07,333 INFO  [org.jboss.wsf.framework.management.DefaultEndpointRegistry] remove: jboss.ws:context=AxisWebService1,endpoint=AxisBank
11:23:07,335 ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Real: name=vfs:///D:/Workspaces/workspace_working/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/jboss-6.0.0.Final/deploy/AxisWebService1EAR.ear state=PreReal mode=Manual requiredState=Real: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error during deploy: vfs:///D:/Workspaces/workspace_working/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/jboss-6.0.0.Final/deploy/AxisWebService1EAR.ear/AxisWebService1.war/
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:185) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1603) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:154) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.system.tools.ProfileServiceToolsFacade.addURI(ProfileServiceToolsFacade.java:233) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.tools.LegacyDeploymentScannerAdapter.addURL(LegacyDeploymentScannerAdapter.java:140) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.tools.DeploymentScanner.addURL(DeploymentScanner.java:91) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.tools.DeploymentScanner.addURL(DeploymentScanner.java:83) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [:1.6.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0]
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:271) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:670) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.jmx.MBeanServerWrapper.invoke(MBeanServerWrapper.java:138) [:6.0.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.0.0.Final date: 20101228)]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1424) [:1.6.0]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$200(RMIConnectionImpl.java:72) [:1.6.0]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1262) [:1.6.0]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1357) [:1.6.0]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:786) [:1.6.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [:1.6.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:305) [:1.6.0]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159) [:1.6.0]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.6.0]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155) [:1.6.0]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535) [:1.6.0]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790) [:1.6.0]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649) [:1.6.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885) [:1.6.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907) [:1.6.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [:1.6.0]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: /resource/hibernate1.cfg.xml
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.configuration.NonSpringBusHolder.newInstance(NonSpringBusHolder.java:168) [:3.4.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.configuration.NonSpringBusHolder.configure(NonSpringBusHolder.java:98) [:3.4.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.aspect.BusDeploymentAspect.start(BusDeploymentAspect.java:110) [:3.4.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.webservices.integration.deployers.WSDeploymentAspectDeployer.internalDeploy(WSDeploymentAspectDeployer.java:123) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.0.GA]
    ... 70 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: /resource/hibernate1.cfg.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1491) [:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1425) [:3.6.0.Final]
    at axisBank.WebService.AxisBankImpl.(AxisBankImpl.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [:1.6.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39) [:1.6.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) [:1.6.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) [:1.6.0]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355) [:1.6.0]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308) [:1.6.0]
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.configuration.NonSpringBusHolder.newInstance(NonSpringBusHolder.java:164) [:3.4.1.GA]
    ... 75 more
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: unknown protocol: classpath Nested exception: unknown protocol: classpath
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484) [:1.6.1]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1481) [:3.6.0.Final]
    ... 84 more

Please find the below hibernate code

"


 
  com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  test
  jdbc:mysql://testserver:3306/nadnewdb
  test
  org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
  org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory
thread

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
```

"

Comment: I want to know why hibernate-cfg file is not able to be detected.

Comment: This file is not able to be detected only when the ear file is deployed if we run the java file independentantly, it is running fine

Comment: I am getting the below error:

Comment: Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: hibernate.sourceforge.net Nested exception: hibernate.sourceforge.net
 at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484) [:1.6.1]
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1481)

Comment: Could you post your hibernate config and log4j xml

Comment: below is the hibernate.cfg.xml file

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="AxisbankSession">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://testserver:3306/testdb</property>

Comment: <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>  
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

Comment: <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
  <mapping class="com.test.model.testTransactionInfo" resource="com/test/model/testTransactionInfo.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping class="com.test.model.ErrorCode" resource="com/test/model/testCode.hbm.xml"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>

Comment: sorry could not upload the document so pasted the code here

Comment: What do you meant by not uploading document. Copy the content and paste after editing your question